# Neos Performance

Tags: performance, ubuntu-12.04, neoscms

I´m new at Neos and the concept is perfect for my needs! So thank you for developing this.
But I installed the cms on my vServer and ist takes about 7.4sec to load the page!
When I open the Backend menu it takes about 30sec to load all things from there.

I have no idea why this takes so long.

I´ve included a picture of the chrome developer tools network section, you can see there the long loading time.

[image]

I`ve already checked my server and no other processes running and could slow down the delevery process of neos.

So I hope you have an idea to solve this issue, because in this state it is to slow to use it in production environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you set the context to production as described in the [docs](http://neos.typo3.org/download.html)?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    SetEnv FLOW_CONTEXT Production
    ..
</VirtualHost>
```

Otherwise it runs in development mode, where it always checks for changes.

Comment: I´ve tried this but when I use these config I got an Internal Server Error 500. It looks like this: [link](http://soen.h2259214.stratoserver.net) '500 Internal Server Error

An internal error occurred.

When contacting the maintainer of this application please mention the following reference code:

20140125145639102006'

Comment: I´ve solved this Problem. Now the site works and loads in about 2seconds. That good but I think the time now relies on my vServer.

Comment: And how did you resolve the problem? It might help others reading this some time.

Comment: I´ve run this on my servers terminal:                                                      FLOW_CONTEXT=Production ./flow flow:cache:flush
FLOW_CONTEXT=Production ./flow flow:cache:warmup



and added two lines in Typo3-Neos-1.0/Web/index.php:

...
} elseif (substr($rootPath, -1) !== '/') {
$rootPath .= '/';
}

putenv ("FLOW_REWRITEURLS=1"); 
putenv ("FLOW_CONTEXT=Production");

require($rootPath .
...

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the answer by StepenKing, the long load times come from caches being rebuild on every request. Flow, which is the framework Neos is based on, does a lot of magic behind the curtains, like building Proxy classes which allow the use of dependency injection. Those proxies are cached, so they don't have to be rebuilt with every request, since this a very heavy task to do. However, when you are developing you application, you want every change that you make to take immediate effect.

This is why caches are being rebuilt on every request, when you run the Application in Development context. The directive SetEnv FLOW_CONTEXT Production will make your installation to run in Production context. In production context, caches will only be rebuilt on the first request or when you manually trigger it. This will make your application run mugh faster.