# Typo3 Neos performance for css and js

Tags: performance, docker, neoscms

I installed Typo3 Neos, Apache and MySQL in a Docker container. The initial page loads in about a second, which seems okay to me. But most css-, javascript- and font-files take extremely long to load, some over 20 seconds waiting time.

A chromium network timeline screenshot can be found on http://postimg.org/image/j3io3s0in/.
All files except the initial html exist as actual files. (I am not familiar enough with neos to say whether they are used, though.)

My apache config contains `SetEnv FLOW_CONTEXT Production`, and I grepped through the directory where neos is installed to make sure it is not overwritten anywhere.
I also used `FLOW_CONTEXT=Production ./flow flow:cache:flush` followed by `FLOW_CONTEXT=Production ./flow flow:cache:warmup` to restart the caches, and even after this and several page loads, the site stays the same.

Any help on how to bring this to adequate performance would be greatly appreciated.
- Simon Kohlmeyer

PS: This is different from [Neos Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21349907/typo3-neos-performance) in that NehalemWars problem is with the generated html, while mine are with all other files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very unlikely to be related to Neos/Flow directly since what happens is that there is a symlink created for the static resources. So it's likely more related to the system environment and it's handling of symlinks or similar. Neos/Flow is never executed when fetched static resources at all and creates the symlinks if not already available when rendering the response.

Comment: That put me in a good direction. Curiously enough, if I open the css/js files by themselves, they load instantly. Looks like an Apache problem.

Comment: Turns out, I actually misconfigured Apache. Thanks for the hint!